# Snowflake csv file copy error - Unknown user-defined function T.TRY_TO_DECIMAL

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to load a CSV file. I successfully loaded it into a staging table. I have also been able to copy the data successfully into the final table, but the decimal data types were rounded off in the process. I am trying to write a new copy process that casts some of the datatypes to decimal, but I am getting an error: "Unknown user-defined function T.TRY_TO_DECIMAL"

---

use warehouse P_TEMP_WH;
alter warehouse P_TEMP_WH resume;

-- Query the staged data file
select t.$1,t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5,t.$6,t.$7,t.$8,t.$9,t.$10,t.$11,t.$12,t.$13,t.$14,t.$15,t.$16,t.$17,t.$18,t.$19,t.$20,t.$21,t.$22,t.$23,t.$24,t.$25,t.$26,t.$27,t.$28,t.$29,t.$30  from @%players t;

-- Convert the staged CSV column data to the specified data types before loading it into the destination table

copy into PLAYERS(rk,
player,
pos,
age,
team,
games,
games_started,
minutes_played,
field_goals,
field_goals_attempted,
field_goal_percentage,
threes,
three_points_attempted,
three_point_percentage,
two_pointers,
two_pointers_attempted,
two_point_percentage,
effective_field_goal_percentage,
free_throws,
free_throws_attempted,
free_throw_percentage,
offensive_rebounds,
defensive_rebounds,
total_rebound_percentage,
assists,
steals,
blocks,
turnovers,
fouls,
points)
from (
select t.$1,t.$2,t.$3,t.$4,t.$5,t.$6 ,t.$7,t.$8,t.$9,TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$10, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$11, '99.9',9,5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$12, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$13, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$14, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$15, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$16, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$17, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$18, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$19, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$20, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$21, '99.9', 9, 5),t.TRY_TO_DECIMAL($22, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$23, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$24, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$25, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$26, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$27, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$28, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$29, '99.9', 9, 5),TRY_TO_DECIMAL(t.$30, '99.9', 9, 5)

from @%players t
)

Comment: in your query, you have in one place `t.TRY_TO_DECIMAL($22, '99.9', 9, 5)`. Will it work if you remove `t.` ?

Comment: Thank you - I was staring at it too long. That got rid of the problem. Now I have another issue with "Can't parse '0.405' as number with format '?" but I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Needed to change t.TRY_TO_DECIMAL($22, '99.9', 9, 5) to t.TRY_TO_DECIMAL($22, '9.999', 9, 5)